# How know if user is visitor or logged member?

Tags: users, 8

How can I determine programatically whether the current user is anonymous or authenticated?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For the sake of more robust and descriptive code, you can make use of the handy [`User::isAnonymous()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AisAnonymous/8) method, e.g.

```
if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
  // Anonymous user...
}
```

Comment: Whenever possible, use methods like this: program to the interface not the implementation.  Using an IDE w/ code completion is invaluable for Drupal 8 work.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, note that  \Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated() is the equivalent of D7 user_is_logged_in()

Comment: I created a custom module and I can't get this function to work. Is there something additional I need to add in my module? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

```
  $current= \Drupal::currentUser();
  if (!$current->id()) {
    // is visitor
  }
  else {
    // is logged
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

`isAnonymous()` holds the danger of not working when a site is saving data (for example in forms) in `PrivateTempStore`. Therefore, i prefer the following:

```
if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
  // This user is logged in.
} else {
  // This user is anonymous.
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why `::isAnonymous()` is different from `not ::isAuthenticated()`?

Answer (score 1):

Methods that you can use in Drupal 8 to check:

Use the **isAuthenticated()** method on the user. For example, use the following code to determine the state of the current user:

```
$logged_in = \Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated();
```

Use **isAnonymous()** to determine if the user is anonymous:

```
$anynomous_user = \Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous();
```

Answer (score -5):

U can use this code::

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == 0) {
  //user is not logged in
}else{
  //user is logged in
}
```

Comment: Drupal code works for Drupal 7, but not in Drupal 8

Comment: Yeah and use === for strict comparison and put space before and after your else for coding standards :/

Comment: This code could match with an user that is being created, because $user->uid is NULL before the first save(). 
The NULL response on the uid would match with the == 0.